# VB.Net development in Ubuntu - Build error in Monodevelop

Tags: linux, vb.net, ubuntu, monodevelop, build-error

I want to start coding in VB.Net but I have a Linux machine ATM i don't want to switch to Windows.
I installed MonoDevelop on my Ubuntu 16.04 by following the steps from their page: http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/. Everything is fine until I try to run the program I get the following error:

**/home/user/Projects/Project/Project/Project.vbproj: Error: Target named 'Build' not found in the project.**

I searched around for a solution but didn't find any. Didn't mess with any of the settings just created the project and tried to compile. Is there anything extra i had to install/set maybe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I alsa have the same problem, could anybody help?

Comment: Problem solved by installing Windows and switching to Visual Studio :)